# Extends android.app.Service and implements android.content.ServiceConnection in c

Tags: android, c++

I am working on a multi platform mobile project. We are using c++ mixing with objective c or calling java function directly (NDK) to achieve this. I would like to keep that idiom and not writing any java codes.

I would like to implement Google in-app billing, but the billing service requires extending Service and Implements ServiceConnection from the Android SDK. Will the following code works?

**BillingService.h**

```
#include "android/app/Service.hpp"
#include "android/content/ServiceConnect.hpp"

Class BillingService : public Service, public ServiceInterface
{
    virtual void android::content::ServiceConnection::onServiceDisconnected(local_ref<   android::content::ComponentName > const &a0) = 0;

    virtual void android::content::ServiceConnection::onServiceConnected(local_ref< android::content::ComponentName > const &a0, local_ref< android::os::IBinder > const &a1) = 0;

    virtual void void onCreate() = 0;

    // all other method in Service that need to be extends .... 
 }
```